# Median Filter Implementation In Python

Tags: python, image, iteration, signal-processing

I implemented median filter in Python in order to remove the salt & pepper noise from the images. It is working fine and all but I would love to hear your advice or opinions.

```
def median_filter(data, filter_size):
    temp = []
    indexer = filter_size // 2
    for i in range(len(data)):

        for j in range(len(data[0])):

            for z in range(filter_size):
                if i + z - indexer < 0 or i + z - indexer > len(data) - 1:
                    for c in range(filter_size):
                        temp.append(0)
                else:
                    if j + z - indexer < 0 or j + indexer > len(data[0]) - 1:
                        temp.append(0)
                    else:
                        for k in range(filter_size):
                            temp.append(data[i + z - indexer][j + k - indexer])

            temp.sort()
            data[i][j] = temp[len(temp) // 2]
            temp = []
    return data
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make the complete sense to me. Could you explain a little what it does? Why do you loop through `filter_size` on two of the three options in the `for z in range(filter_size)` loop?

Comment: Sure, Median filter is usually used to reduce noise in an image. My code basically takes the array of the image which is corrupted by salt and pepper noise and remove the noise. I loop through "filter_size" because there are different sized median filters, like 3x3, 5x5. So there is more pixels that need to be considered. You can take a look at the GitHub repo, https://github.com/MeteHanC/Python-Median-Filter

Comment: could you answer my second question? I don't really understand how you handle those median filters going out of bounds.

Comment: I check the rows and columns going out of bounds with different if statements. So if a columns value is negative, I append zeros to the temp array. Adding zeros in the situation of an out bound, is a common approach. And if row value is not negative , I check the column value. And append zeros if out of bounds again. And about "i+z-indexer", with this way I put the current pixel in the hotspot(basically center of the array) and I check its surrounding pixels. For 3x3 median filter, lets say we got the [0][0] pixel. So program will check [-1][-1], [-1][0], [-1][1], [0][-1], [0][0], [0][1] so on

Comment: I have a problem with your code I don't know why it has an error of sort function for me.and also in this code same error in line 18 (for a, b in window) "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous." can you help me with that plz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Code review

Peilonrays points out a mixup with the out-of-bounds testing that is valid. The statement `if j ...` must be within the loop `for k ...`. One of the results is that you add a different number of elements to `temp` depending on which boundary you're at. But there are better ways to avoid out-of-bounds indexing, see below.

Your biggest bug, however, is that you write the result of the filter into the image you are processing. Median filtering cannot be done in-place. When you update `data[i][j]`, you'll be reading the updated value to compute `data[i][j+1]`. You need to allocate a new image, and write the result there.

I would suggest not adding zeros for out-of-bounds pixels at all, because it introduces a bias to the output pixels near the boundary. The clearest example is for the pixels close to any of the corners. At the corner pixel, with a 3x3 kernel, you'll have 4 image pixels covered by the kernel. Adding 5 zeros for the out-of-bounds pixels guarantees that the output will be 0. For larger kernels this happens in more pixels of course. Instead, it is easy to simply remove the `temp.append(0)` statements, leading to a non-biased result. Other options are to read values from elsewhere in the image, for example mirroring the image at the boundary or extending the image by extrapolation. For median filtering this has little effect, IMO.

You set `temp = []` at the very beginning of your function, then reset it when you're done using it, in preparation for the next loop. Instead, initialize it once inside the main double-loop over the pixels:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
   for j in range(len(data[0])):
      temp = []
      # ...
```

You're looping over `i` and `j` as image indices, then over `z` and `c` or `k` for filter kernel indices. `c` and `k` have the same function in two different loops, I would suggest using the same variable for that. `z` doesn't really fit in with either `c` or `k`. I would pick two names that are related in the way that `i` and `j` are, such as `m` and `n`. The choice of variable names is always very limited if it's just one letter. Using longer names would make this code clearer: for example `img_column`, `img_row`, `kernel_column`, `kernel_row`.

---

## Out-of-bounds checking

This concludes my comments on your code. Now I'd like to offer some alternatives for out-of-bounds checking. These tests are rather expensive when performed for every pixel -- it's a test that is done \$n k\$ times (with \$n\$ pixels in the image and \$k\$ pixels in the kernel). Maybe in Python the added cost is relatively small, it's an interpreted language after all, but for a compiled language these tests can easily amount to doubling processing time. There are 3 common alternatives that I know of. I will use `border = filter_size // 2`, and presume `filter_size` is odd. It is possible to adjust all 3 methods to even-sized filters.

#### Separate loops for image border pixels

The idea here is that the loop over the first and last `border` pixels along each dimension are handled separately from the loop over the core of the image. This avoids all tests. But it does require some code duplication (all in the name of speed!).

```
for i in range(border):
   # here we loop over the kernel from -i to border+1
for i in range(border, len(data)-border):
   # here we loop over the full kernel
for i in range(len(data)-border, len(data)):
   # here we loop over the kernel from -border to len(data)-i
```

Of course, within each of those loops, a similar set of 3 loops is necessary to loop over `j`. The filter logic is thus repeated 9 times. In a compiled language, where this is the most efficient method, code duplication can be avoided with inlined functions or macros. I don't know how a Python function call compares to a bunch of tests for out-of-bounds access, so can't comment on the usefulness of this method in Python.

#### A separate code path for border pixels

The idea here is to do out-of-bounds checking only for those pixels that are close to the image boundary. For pixels within the border, you use a version of the filtering logic with out-of-bounds checking. For the pixels in the core of the image (which is the big majority of pixels), you use a second version of the logic without out-of-bounds checking.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
   i_border = i < border or i >= len(data)-border
   for j in range(len(data[0])):
      j_border = j < border or j >= len(data)-border
      if i_border or j_border:
         # filtering with bounds checking
      else:
         # filtering without bounds checking
```

#### Padding the image

The simplest solution, and also the most flexible one, is to create a temporary image that is larger than the input image by `2*border` along each dimension, and copy the input image into it. The "new" pixels can be filled with zeros (to replicate what OP intended to do), or with values taken from the input image (for example by mirroring the image at the boundary or extrapolating in some other way).

The filter now never needs to check for out-of-bounds reads. When the filtering kernel is placed over any of the input image pixels, all samples fall within the padded image.

Since for this type of filtering it is necessary to create a new output image anyway (it is not possible to compute it in-place, as I mentioned before), this is not a huge cost: the original input image can now be re-used as output image.

This solution leads to the simplest code, allows for all sorts of boundary extension methods without complicating the filtering code, and often results in the fastest code too.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a few bugs.

1. > ```
   > if i + z - indexer < 0 or i + z - indexer > len(data) - 1:
   > ```

   If `i` and `z` are `0`, where `indexer` is 1, then you'll have `0 + 0 - 1 < 0`. This would mean that you'd replace the data in `(-1, j)`, `(0, j)` and `(1, j)` to 0. Since 0 and 1 probably do contain data this is just plain wrong.
2. > ```
   > if j + z - indexer < 0 or j + indexer > len(data[0]) - 1:
   >       temp.append(0)
   > ```

   This removes some data, meaning that the median is shifted. Say you should have `(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3)`, however you removed the first three because of this you'd have `(0, 1, 2, 3)`. Now the median is `1` rather than `0`.

---

Your code would be simpler if you:

1. Made a window list, that contained all the indexes that you want to move to.
2. Have an if to check if the data in that index is out of bounds.
3. If it's out of bounds default to 0.
4. If it's not out of bounds use the data.

This could become:

```
def median_filter(data, filter_size):
    temp = []
    indexer = filter_size // 2
    window = [
        (i, j)
        for i in range(-indexer, filter_size-indexer)
        for j in range(-indexer, filter_size-indexer)
    ]
    index = len(window) // 2
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[0])):
            data[i][j] = sorted(
                0 if (
                    min(i+a, j+b) < 0
                    or len(data) <= i+a
                    or len(data[0]) <= j+b
                ) else data[i+a][j+b]
                for a, b in window
            )[index]
    return data
```

Comment: That is the whole point, replacing those values with 0. As I said adding zeros, it is very common approach. Probably I couldnt make myself clear to you in the comment section, sorry about that Thank you for your comments

Comment: @M.Han Please read my answer again. You're changing too many values to black. If changing valid data to black was 'the whole point', then you'd want to just change the code to `data[i][j] = 0`...

Comment: @M.Han Is `(0, 0)` meant to be replaced to black?

Comment: The window list not only makes the code simpler, it also allows for arbitrary window shapes. A circular window has much nicer properties than a square one. It is easy to implement that with this code. Nice!